# Run local python file using Gcloud terminal tool

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, gcloud, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I can connect to gcp using Gcloud terminal tool to run connect remote(gcp vm) jupyter lab on local pc to 8080 port.

```
gcloud compute ssh --project project-name --zone us-east1-b my-vm -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

But is there any method to run local python file using gcloud terminal tool?
I mean I will not upload python file to the VM using scp ,it will stay in my local pc and like the jupyter lab it will use GCP-VM(my-vm in my above command) as backend . Can I do that ?

If I become more specific,
when I write gcloud start or stop vm command for example

```
gcloud compute instances start my-vm --zone abc
```

I don't need to write a ssh connection command externally .The public/private key is already saved and i think gcloud terminal tool can handle that .

I was looking for something like that to run python [this command doesn't exist ] like ,

```
gcloud compute instances my-vm --zone abc --run-python-file test.py [this command doesn't exist ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably.

How do you want the Python code to interact with the Jupyter notebook?

If the Python code interacts using tcp over `localhost:8080`, it will work as-is.

Summarizing the discussion in comments: in order to run (Python) scripts on the VM, scripts must be copied to the VM, invoked and then any output copied back from the VM. There's no standard way to do this.

Steps:

1. [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) to copy files to the VM
2. [`gcloud compute ssh ... --command=".."`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#--command)
3. Possibly [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) to copy files from the VM

> **NOTE** `gcloud compute scp` and `gcloud compute ssh` are convenience-wrappers for the underlying Linux `scp` and `ssh` commands

> **NOTE** In this case, using Python, the `command` needs to ensure that Python has been installed on the VM before it can be used

Comment: Actually I was trying to run my local python file automatically using gcp vm as back end.I cannot do that using jupyter lab as I need browser.So I need a way to do all this in terminal command so that I can make a single program to automate all this process .[connect to gcp-> run python file locally using gcp gpu-> get reuslt]

Comment: I remain unclear as to what you're trying to do, sorry. If I understand correctly, you've installed Jupyter notebook (server) on a VM and you're ssh tunneling to the VM to access its browser client. You can run Python code in the notebook (on the VM). You can run Puthon code locally but it would need a means to interact with a server (perhaps the notebook or something else you've created or installed) on the VM.

Comment: when I write gcloud start or stop vm command for example "gcloud compute instances start my-vm --zone abc" I dont need to write a ssh connection command externally .The public/private key is already saved and i think gcloud terminal tool can handle that .I was looking for something like that to run python [this command doesn't exist ] like "gcloud compute instances my-vm --zone abc --run-python-file test.py 
"

Comment: Ah, I see. There's no command that will transfer a file and run it  you'll need to copy your Python file using something like `[gcloud compute] scp ...`, ensure that the VM has Python installed (presumably it does for Jupyter), and then run it on the VM using something like `gcloud compute ssh ... --command="python3 test.py"` and you'll need to include some way to get the results back from the VM.

Comment: I usually do that but sometimes after starting the vm, first 1-2 command fails to upload file .I am concerned, if it will be a concrete solution for the production phase. I think after starting vm,it takes few seconds to perform properly.

Comment: When you start a VM, various processes must complete before the it stabilizes. You'll need to wait for this before running your script. Unfortunately, short of adding checks to your scripts to determine this, there's not a lot else you can do. I'll update the answer with a summary of my comments, please consider accepting it as an answer. Good luck